# Unable to get updated SSL certificate for a single website on OSX

Tags: macos, ssl, certificate

I'm unable to get a new SSL certificate for a website a use for work, on a specific OSX machine. On other computers I get the certificate which is valid and not expired, on my laptop with OSX High Sierra, the certificate is expired on November 2017 but I can't get a new one, on any browser, no matter what I try to do. I tried deleting the certificate from the keychain but it doesn't matter, all the browsers still complain that the certificate is expired. I tried other OSX machines and it works fine. Where does OSX really store or cache certificates? On the other machine I can't find it in the keychain, but it works.

Comment: Depending on the application maybe the client uses a client certificate that needs to be renewed? Just something that might be relevant.

Comment: It's a wordpress site, but on any other machine it just works without any type of configuration. On my laptop, it's just impossible to get the updated certificate, on any browser, I tried Safari, Chrome, Firefox. They all complain about the certificate being invalid.

Comment: The SSL certificate for a website isn't normally stored on the client *at all*; it's supplied by the server as part of the connection protocol. If the web browser is complaining that the server's certificate is expired, then something really weird (possibly some sort of network hijack) is going on. You should examine the certificate (in Safari, click Show Certificate, examine the chain part near the top, then expand the Details section near the bottom) and see what it indicates about the cert beyond it being expired.

Comment: It could also be a problem with a web proxy. Do you have a proxy configured on that Mac? Check in System Preferences -> Network pane -> Advanced button -> Proxies tab.